# Should a View Model react to events in the View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I've been implementing the MVVM paradigm for a while now while adopting ReactiveCocoa in certain parts of the project. I have a simple question about the lifetime of an object related to a view.

Imagine that whenever the `View` disappears from the screen, the `View` Model needs to update something in an object. Should this updates be called by the `ViewController` or can the `View` Model observe, for example, the **viewWillDisappear** Selector in the `ViewController` and react to it? Would that be a bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use MVVM pattern in order to *decouple* view (and view controllers, which in Cocoa are also considered a part of the View layer) from the model. That means view model should not know anything about the view controller.

As described in [this post](http://www.sprynthesis.com/2014/12/06/reactivecocoa-mvvm-introduction/), ideally you shouldn't even import `UIKit` in your view model.

In other words, a view model should be reusable for displaying the same data in different ways: you may want to display the data in a view controller *and* a plain `UIView` subclass somewhere else (think about having an `PersonViewModel` in `PersonTableViewCell` and in a `PersonDetailsViewController` which is shown after tapping a cell - I think it's a pretty common scenario).

If you somehow observe `viewWillDisappear` in the view model, it is tightly coupled to `UIViewController` subclasses and can't be used with `UIView` subclasses.

Updates to the view model should be called in the view controller in a following way:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [self.viewModel updateStuff];
}
```

Comment: Hey, that makes perfect sense! Thank you for the answer and for sharing that post, taught me a lot.